# object[] vs List<object> vs IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, list, memory-management

I have tons of objects of the same class `obj`, currently defined as `obj[]`.

In most cases these `obj` are just `default(obj)`, wouldn't it be best to implement `IEnumerable<obj>` instead of these `obj[]` lists?

This should release memory for me, right?
Currently these objects (running a memory profiler) are at 200k items (constantly growing).

Would changing the lists to IEnumerables help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual implementation of `List<T>` is based on arrays, so the difference in memory usage between the two will be negligible.

As far as `IEnumerable<T>` is concerned: no, it won't save you any memory.  `null` or `default` elements are perfectly acceptable within an `IEnumerable<T>` and the framework doesn't do anything to filter duplicates.  It can't, since the memory footprint associated with an `IEnumerable<T>` structure are entirely dependent on the class that implements it, and if you just plop an array into an enumerable variable or field, then you aren't changing anything substantial.  Enumerables are also immutable, so the proposed switch would probably be a breaking change from your array implementation.

If you don't care about ordering, you can use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).  This actually *does* filter duplicates, so if many or most of your elements are `default(T)`, then you will only require memory for one of them.  Obviously this will eliminate *all* duplicates, not just default ones, so this choice would only be useful if there is no other duplication.

If you require mutable semantics - as I suspect you do if you're using arrays - then you *could* (and *should*) switch to a mutable interface such as `IList<T>`, and write your own implementation - probably based on `List<T>` - which ignores `default(T)` when you try to add it.  That way you could preserve the order of non- `default` elements without ever allocating any memory to hold the `default` ones.

If you actually need to preserve *all* of the original elements then no simple data structure is going to help you.  Might I suggest a database?  I know that memory is abundant nowadays, but when you're storing hundreds of thousands of items you should at least be *considering* a data structure or system that's designed for that scale.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is just an interface; it doesn't prescribe any way to store data. A `List` just contains an array that grows as you add more items to it, but you can call the [`TrimExcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207.aspx) method to shrink the array.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark has said, IEnumerable is just an interface.  Object[] and List (and most any other generic collection in the .NET framework) actually implement the IEnumerable interface.

A more appropriate question would be whether Object[] or List or LinkedList etc. are better.

An array of Objects (ie Object[]) will have the smallest memory footprint because the List can possibly be double the memory size of an array (depending on how many elements are in the list).  When you add an item to a List and the internal array is full, it doubles the size of the array in an attempt to make the addition of new elements faster on average from an algorithmic perspective.